# How do I calculate mathematically this algorithm's time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I'm trying to understand algorithm's time coplexity and i have some troubles with that. Can someone explain me how do i calculate this algorithm's complexity mathematically?

```
ALG(m,n)

1. if m > n then
2.   return ALG(m - n, n)
3. else if n > m then
4.   return ALG(n, m)
5. else
6.   return n
```

Comment: What have **YOU** tried so far? Share **YOUR** ideas/findings. This is not a 'Do My Homework'-service.

Answer (score 2):

This is a recursive function. When *m > n* then it call this function again with parameter *(m-n, n)*.
So in worst case, suppose when *m = 100*, *n = 1* then the value of parameter in every steps are -

```
 1. m = 100, n = 1
 2. m = 99, n = 1  // because new m will be (m-n), and n remains same according to step 2 in your algorithm
 3. m = 98, n = 1  // same as previous comment
 4. m = 97, n = 1
  .........
  .........
  .........
 99. m = 2, n = 1
 100. m = 1, n = 1
 And then it executes steps 7 in your algorithm.
```

So overall, your algorithm **100** times what is maximum value between m and n.

And when m < n, then you swap these values. After swapping, this algorithm follows the previous steps.

So complexity of this algorithm is ***O(max(m, n))***.

Answer (score 0):

On top of what Faruk Hossain provided.

Upper bound can be reduced additionally to

```
O(n,m) = a/b + b/gcd(a,b) 
  where a = max(n,m) and b = min(n,m)
```

by observing this algorithm calculates gcd. and a/b is number of steps needed that second "if statement kicks" and after that at most `b/gcd(n,m)` additional steps are required once